# Verifying the integral of ${\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{a\cos (\theta - b)}}f\left( {r,\theta } \right)} d\theta }$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I tried doing the above integral in the following way. I am not sure if this is correct. Did I break any fundamental rule? Thank you.
Let, $f(r,\theta)=re^{j\theta}$.

$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}f\left( {r,\theta } \right)} d\theta }\\
{ = {e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {f\left( {r,\theta } \right)} d\theta  - \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\left[ {\frac{{d{e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}}}{{d\theta }}\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {f\left( {r,\theta } \right)} d\theta } \right]} d\theta }\\
{ = {e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}f\left( r \right) - \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\left[ {a\sin (b - \theta ){e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}f\left( r \right)} \right]} d\theta }\\
{ = {e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}f\left( r \right) - f\left( r \right)\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\left[ {a\sin (b - \theta ){e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}} \right]} d\theta }\\
{ = {e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}f\left( r \right) - f(r)*0}\\
{ = {e^{a\cos (\theta  - b)}}f(r)}
\end{array}$

Comment: How does $\int_0^{2\pi}f(r,\theta)\,{\rm d}\theta=f(r)$? This certainly doesn't hold for arbitrary $f$. Are there more assumptions about $f$ given (like continuous, differentiable, periodic, etc.); if so, please include them with an [edit]. Also, you can't pull out a function depending on $\theta$ if you integrate w.r.t. $\theta$ which you do on multiple occasions if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In my case $r$ is the magnitude and $\theta$ is the phase of the corresponding variable such that $x=re^{j\theta}$

Comment: You posted this yesterday [What is the integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {{e^{a\cos (\theta - b)}}f\left( {r,\theta } \right)} d\theta $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744772/what-is-the-integral-of-int-limits-02-pi-ea-cos-theta-bf-left)

Comment: Yes. Then I tried to solve that and add my edited solution later. And i guess it was late and most of them missed my solution approach that I tried. So, I asked that again with my solution here.

Comment: Well your result is wrong. What exactly are you doing in the first equality? Also your final answer is in terms of $\theta$, w.r.t. which you were integrating, so it can't be right.

Comment: In the first equality I tried to use ${\int {u(x)v(x)dx} }$ formula. My main objective is to find the distribution of $f(r)$ such that $f(r)$ is continuous or discrete (this integration is a part of my main objective function that I am working with). I wanted to extract $f(r)$ from the integration. I don't know if there is any theorem that might help me doing that. Thank you.